# Go to the second last line

Tags: vi

I wonder how would you quickly go to/copy/delete until the second last line (the nth line from back in general) in `vi`. I know G moves the cursor to the end of the file but nG jumps to the nth line from top.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: Use `$-1` to reference second to last line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the ex command as

```
:$-1
```

for the penultimate line.  Or

```
:$-n
```

to go to nth line from bottom.

Answer (score 1):

From next line to second last line

```
:.+1,$-1
```

refer
[Vim Tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Ranges)